# Say we're driving a bike and suddenly hold the brakes?

Tags: classical-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, forces

It's easy for me to imagine that if we brake the front wheel then there is a chance that I'll flip.

On the other hand if I brake the back wheel, there is no way it'll happen no matter how fast I brake.

But whether I brake the front wheel or back wheel, the force I've added is a backward force at the bottom of the wheel.

So why the different outcome?

Comment: One force goes "inward", the other "outward" from the CoG.

Comment: Hmm... it's hard to express this without pictures. I am sure you can imagine right? Or perhaps the break at the back wheel only applies when the backwheel touch the ground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The torque is in the same direction in either case, so the torque wants to lift the back-wheel and flip you over the front whichever wheel you brake with, but when the braking is on the back-wheel, if you lift the back-wheel, the braking force goes away, so the torque goes away. This means that a brake applied to the back-wheel will never be enough (unless it is applied *extremely* suddenly) to flip the bike, it will just lift the back wheel and reduce the braking to zero, or else make a bouncing back-wheel.

Comment: This is what I suspected. However, as you said your self, what about if the break is so sudden? I feel as if there is something more to this. Anyway, +1 definitely.